# ABCPDF Spliting / Page Breaking a table header from table data rows

Tags: c#, html, abcpdf

As the title suggests I have a header and data appearing on a separate page. The data rows span more than a page and thus I think it is automatically appearing on a new page.

The pdf has been transformed to landscape but I don't think that matters.

Col1 Col2 COl3 
**New York** 
** Rest of the page empty **

** New Page ** 
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
1 2 4 
1 2 5 
....

Is there anything I can add to allow the data to start immediately after the heading?
Col1 Col2 COl3 
**New York** 
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
1 2 4 
1 2 5 
....

Code: 
The table uses table header rows and header cells for headings and then table rows and table cells for data.

I use
    abcPdfDocument.AddImageHtml(pdfDocumentProperties.ContentHtml, true, 0, true); 
for adding the first page and 
    abcPdfDocument.Page = abcPdfDocument.AddPage();
    documentId = abcPdfDocument.AddImageToChain(documentId);
for adding the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved the issue via the help of ABCPDF support. This issue was specific to my reports due to the complexity, there answer below:

> There are too many vertical lines/borders that forces ABCpdf to try keeping the tables in a single page because you are using cumulative cohesion. You need to use maximum cohesion.
>   theDoc.HtmlOptions.BreakMethod = HtmlBreakMethodType.MaximumCohesion;

After making this change I did not encounter any weird page splitting issues.